# How to write a JSP file for jQuery UI Autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm having trouble to use jquery ui autocomplete with ajax request. In the exemple of jquery ui page we have this:

```
$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
        }
    });
```

So I'm trying to make a search.jsp and I don't know how to use JSON or how to return it to client side.
Let's say I make a simple loop to write some values in an array:

```
String[] arr;
arr = new String[10];

for(int i=0; i<arr.length; arr++){
  arr[i]=i*2+"";
}
```

How can I pass this values to client side using JSON?
Do I need to get 'term' before making this loop?
I'm really lost.
Thanks.

Comment: Lost where? Why are you doing it in a JSP? Are you using a JSON library? Do you know how to set the content type?

Comment: I don't know how to use JSON in a JSP. How can I encode the data to pass to client side to be used by autocomplete?

Comment: JSP just creates a response, it can look like whatever you want, like, say, HTML, or JSON. You'll need to set the content type is all. JSP is just a templating engine.

Comment: Sorry, how can I delete this question? I did not explained it well.

Comment: I believe I understood exactly what you meant--you're over-complicating it. Make your JSP emit text that's valid JSON. Set the content type. Done.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Thanks.